# Replacing negative values with Find and replace text (FART)

Tags: windows-8, command-line, find-and-replace

I am trying to replace a positive value with a negative one using FAR. However the utility tries to use the - sign for the options and errors out, displaying the options list. I've tried including the values in quotes but that doesn't work. Other suggestions on google work for special characters apart from "-". I'll appreciate suggestions.

Here is a screenshot of the command prompt:

[image: Screenshot of the command prompt]

Comment: You getting any of my messages? Have you see [Accepting an Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so you understand how that works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the hyphen (**`-`**) character with the backslash (**`\`**) character while using `-C` parameter to tell it to use extended characters and it should work just fine.

I confirmed with the below syntax that it works just as you explain you need it to work.

### Working Syntax

```
fart C:\folder\test\test.txt -C "5000" "\-5218"
```

---

### Further Resources

- `FART /?`

  `-C, --c-style       Allow C-style extended characters (\xFF\0\t\n\r\\ etc.)`